# Cordova Plugin Remove Error "Gen not supported"

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When i am trying to remove cordova plugin using following command :
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4

**its giving me "Error: gen not supported."**

Not found anything on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed gen folder from platforms and re-type the command. its Done